# Libre office modifying/producing overlapping text which was from MS Word document

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

The document below shows text perfectly in MS Office in Windows. But when I download it in Ubuntu, it has overlapping text. Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One** of the possible reasons for this is : ***Unsupported fonts***.

Step 1 : From Windows, copy this folder : **`C:\Windows\Fonts`**.

Step 2 : Create a new folder in **`/home`** directory with the name **`.fonts`** (dont forget the dot ".").

Step 3 : Copy the content inside **`Fonts`** of Windows to **`.fonts`** and also to **`/use/share/fonts`** (if you want to use them system wide).

Step 4 : Rebuild your font-cache with **`fc-cache -f -v`** or reboot.

**Workaround** : If you are not comfortable with LibreOffice, you can install MS Office using **`Wine`** (which is not a good idea).