# Are .fon kind of fonts supported in ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, fonts

I had a problem with libre office (overlapping text with images) as mentioned in my previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740887/libre-office-modifying-producing-overlapping-text-which-was-from-ms-word-documen) .
So I copied Fonts from windows and placed it in `/usr/share/fonts` .
Some fonts from windows are of `.fon` and some are of `.TTF` type .

I found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205969/how-do-i-port-a-fon-font-to-a-linux-font) but I am not aware of using [LinuxFont](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxfont/) project.I am expecting a detailed answer.

Comment: @anonymous2 I saw that . But I don't know how to go about and make use of [Linuxfont](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxfont/) project. I am expecting a detailed answer

Comment: @rohith , Could you update the question to reflect that?

Comment: @Sneetsher okay :)